# Are TBB data objects usable with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, tbb

I have a C++ program which is working quite well using OpenMP to parallelize loops.

However, there are some pieces of code—those which employ queues and priority queues and the like—which would only work in parallel if I declared access to them critical.

An alternative option would be to use TBB data objects, such as `concurrent_queue`. But can I use these data objects with OpenMP and without any of the rest of the TBB?

Sources and links appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update**

For instance, is the following kind of mix of TBB and OpenMP allowed?

```
concurrent_queue<int> queue;
#pragma omp parallel for
for( int i=0; i<1000; i++ )
    queue.push(i);
```

Comment: another alternative is cilk++

Comment: Thanks @pyCthon. It didn't seem to be available in my repositories, so I'm loathe to use it. I'll keep it in mind, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement others' answers, the info you are looking for can also be found in the TBB Tutorial (see [latest TBB documentation](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=91)). A couple of excerpts:

> Intel® Threading Building Blocks is compatible with other threading
>   packages. Because the library is not designed to address all threading problems,
>   it can coexist seamlessly with other threading packages.

-

> Intel® Threading Building Blocks provides highly concurrent container
>   classes. These containers can be used with raw Windows* or Linux* threads, or in
>   conjunction with task-based programming.

Answer (score 1):

TBB is designed to work with openMP, in the programmer manual it list what works.

You could always change the critical sections to TBB mutex, or std::mutex with scoped_locks.

Answer (score 0):

All of the concurrent data structures and synchronization objects in tbb will work just fine with OpenMP (the tasking will as well, but that might be a bit silly).

Comment: Rick, your answer includes neither sources nor links. I do recall reading that TBB and OpenMP threads can coexist, but that this can lead to over-committing one's cores. Which is not just silly, but bad practice.

Comment: I contributed to the specs for several of the data structures and am quite familiar with them, look at my profile. All the concurrent_foo data structures are thread safe within tbb and openmp, the locks and atomic classes can be used as well.
You can find this information in the TBB documentation if you choose to look for it.

Comment: I have always thought that one of the beautiful things about stackoverflow is the way in which it aggregates knowledge which is scattered across many sources into one easily searchable location. Your profile is not an obvious source of information, nor is your assertion alone sufficient. I have been looking through the documentation, but have not yet found a clear or concise answer there. If you know where it is, I invite you to post it here.

Comment: http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/features&benefits.php under compatibility. It's also listed in section 12.2.8 of the reference manual.